# How to compute vector product if there are imaginary numbers, in Prolog?

Tags: vector, prolog

I am trying to multiply two vectors in Prolog but, if those vectors contain imaginary numbers, I can't get it to work. My code so far:

```
vector_product([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],OP) :-
    inner(Xs,Ys,OP1),
    OP is X*Y+OP1.
vector_product([],[],0).
```

Comment: If your vectors contain imaginary numbers, you'll certainly have a special representation for them, and, therefore, you'll need a function that receives two of these numbers and return the resulting product. Unless Prolog has builtin functions to deal with imaginaries -- which I doubt --, you'll have to write them by yourself.

Comment: How are you writing your complex numbers?

Comment: I don't need complex numbers, just imaginary numbers. I'm writing them as a different functor in Prolog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this could help you...

Formulae from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number):

```
% (a+bi) + (c+di) = (a+c) + (b+d)i
c_sum((A,B), (C,D), (E,F)) :- E is A+C, F is B+D.

% (a+bi) (c+di) = (ac-bd) + (bc+ad)i
c_mul((A,B), (C,D), (E,F)) :- E is A*C - B*D, F is B*C + A*D.
```

Numbers are represented as `(Real, Imaginary)`.

```
vector_product([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], OP) :-
    vector_product(Xs, Ys, OP1),
    c_mul(X, Y, M),
    c_sum(M, OP1, OP).
vector_product([], [], (0,0)).
```

Comment: That actually helped figuring it out. Thanks a lot!